# How does web.py handle url mapping?

Tags: python, web.py

edit - the question was not properly researched. The problem turned out to be that the map was not being matched against the url I thought it was.

I understand basically how the mechanism works: odd-numbered entries are treated as regular expressions, and they are automatically encapsulated with `^` and `$`. What I'm hoping somebody can explain is how web.py chooses which entry to use when multiple patterns match.

For example, let's say we matched the url `/` against this mapping:

```
urls = (
    '/'   , 'index',
    '/.*' , 'details')
```

I would expect web.py to choose the first match, `index`, but instead it chooses `details`. Why? Does it look for the last match? Or the most specific match? If it's specificity, how is that determined, string length? Or is it unpredictable?

Comment: it seems to pick up index for me. I also looked at the source code `https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/application.py`, specific at the constructor, and `handle`, `_match` functions and it seems to do an in order for-loop stopping at the first match... so... you must be crazy

Comment: I took a closer look at my code and realized the problem has nothing to do with this question: the server is passing the script the wrong REQUEST_URI. But thanks for clearing up web.py's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It regular expression match, and the first match get chosen. Here ".*" means any thing or nothing, for details you can refer regular expression syntax. If you give it:

```
http://the.server.name:8080/
```

It should choose the first -- "index"

For:

```
http://the.server.name:8080/anything_include_space...
```

it should choose "details"